# Can I clear multiple structs with one call to StructClear()?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm interested in clearing multiple structs I use in a large loop.  Can I pass multiple structs to a single instance of StructClear():

```
StructClear( Struct1, Struct2, Struct3 );
```

or do I have to call it multiple times:

```
StructClear( Struct1 );
StructClear( Struct2 );
StructClear( Struct3 );
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to work with this is you could nest your structs in one master struct...then if you wanted to clear all, clear the master struct.

```
<cfset masterObj = StructNew()/>
<cfset masterObj.users = StructNew()/>
<cfset masterObj.users.firstname = "kevin"/>
<cfset masterObj.users.age = 31/>
<cfset masterObj.browsers = StructNew()/>
<cfset masterObj.browsers.agent = "Mozilla"/>

<cfset StructClear(masterObj)/>
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  This works like a charm and provides the ease of clearing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

StructClear take one argument only so it is not possible

See Adobe live doc here.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_16.html